# How to set text button in tkinter as output from another method within same class?

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, button, tic-tac-toe

I am trying to write 'improved' version of tic-tac-toe game using tkinter GUI. I would like to use select_square() method to print out X or O on button according to button_clicked().

```
from tkinter import *
from board import Board
from player import Player
from functools import partial


class BoardInterface:

    def __init__(self):
        self.all_buttons = []
        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.title("Welcome to Tic-Tac-Toe Game")
        self.choose_symbol()
        self.window.mainloop()


    def choose_symbol(self):
        self.label = Label(text="Choose X/O", font=("Arial", 20, "normal"))
        self.label.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.button_x = Button(font=('Arial', '10'), height=5, width=10, command=lambda: self.button_clicked(self.button_x))
        self.button_x["text"] = "X"
        self.button_x.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.button_o = Button(text="O", font=('Arial', '10'), height=5, width=10, command=lambda: self.button_clicked(self.button_o))
        self.button_o.grid(row=1, column=1)

    def button_clicked(self, button):
        if button["text"] == "X":
            self.label.config(text="X selected")
            self.button_x.destroy()
            self.button_o.destroy()
            self.print_board()
            return "x"
        else:
            self.label.config(text="O selected")
            self.button_x.destroy()
            self.button_o.destroy()
            self.print_board()
            return "o"



    def print_board(self):
        index = 0
        for i in range(1,4):
            for j in range(1,4):
                self.button = Button(text=index, font=('Arial', '10'), height=5, width=10, command=partial(self.select_square, index))
                self.button.grid(row=i, column=j)
                self.all_buttons.append(self.button)
                index += 1


    def select_square(self, index):
        print(index)
        self.bname = self.all_buttons[index]
        self.bname["text"] = "X"
```

Comment: Simply use an instance variable to store the selection.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit of a hack, seems to work well ...

```py
import tkinter
import tkinter.font as tkFont
from tkinter import TclError


class App(tkinter.Tk):
    _state = 0
    _turn = False
    buttons = [[None for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(3)]

    def take_turn(self, i, j):
        button = self.buttons[i][j]
        if button['text']:
            return
        if self._turn:
            button['text'] = 'X'
        else:
            button['text'] = 'O'
        self._state = self._state + 1
        self._turn = not self._turn
        # TODO: check if game finished

    def game_reset(self, _):
        if self._state:
            self._state = 0
            self._turn = False
            for i in range(3):
                for j in range(3):
                    self.buttons[i][j]['text'] = ''
        else:
            self.destroy() # quick exit with ESC-ESC

    def game_state(self):
        pass

    def _resize(self, event):
        # main window has no master
        if event.widget.master:
            # button size change?
            return
        w, h = event.width, event.height
        # must be non-square event
        if w == h:
            return
        dim = min(w, h)
        event.widget.geometry(f'{dim}x{dim}')
        # block further processing of this event
        return "break"

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title('Tic-Tac-Toe')
        self.minsize(200, 200)
        try:
            # windows only (remove the minimize/maximize button)
            # TODO: change window attributes to disable min/max
            self.attributes('-toolwindow', True)
        except TclError:
            print('Not supported on your platform')

        font = tkFont.Font(family = 'Times New Roman', size = 20)
        for i in range(3):
            self.columnconfigure(i, weight=1)
            self.rowconfigure(i, weight=1)
            for j in range(3):
                # width of one is needed to prevent button resizing with text is changed
                # text button with is in characters, image button in pixels
                button = tkinter.Button(self, width = 1, font = font,
                    command = lambda _i = i, _j = j: self.take_turn(_i, _j),
                )
                button.grid(row = i, column = j, sticky='nsew', padx = 2, pady = 2)
                self.buttons[i][j] = button
        self.bind("<Escape>", self.game_reset)
        self.bind('<Configure>', self._resize)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Edit: cleaned it up, looks and responds really well now.

Comment: This answer would be better if you explained what you did, so we don't have to compare this code to the original, line-by-line and character-by-character.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the code was short enough to read. I create a 2D array for the buttons and pass the coordinates to a common button function using a lambda. We can't just pass the button objects because they don't exist at the time when the function is assigned.


The original attempts to use an array - which is also effective.

Comment: The change in code design is to reduce UI updates - creating a snappy/responsive interface.